Is it possible to organize PostgreSQL connections into folders in QGIS Browser?
Is there any way to organize PostgreSQL connections into folders? I use several dozen connections, and it gets messy in the Browser panel. The ability to organize individual connections into folders would be useful.


I don't know of any such option. Maybe a feature request?

Please add feature requests for QGIS here - with an example https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/48091 Feature request: Note:3.40 is due in February and is in a release candidate state. There are no guarantees that feature requests make it to a final release.
